# Using different order by with union

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a query like

```
    select top 10 * from A
    order by price
    union
    select top 3 * from A 
    order by price
```

or sth like that

```
    select top 10 * from A
    where name like '%smt%'
    order by price
    union
    select top 3 * from A
    where name not like '%smt%'
    order by price
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: In what order do you want the final result? If there are rows that appear in both subselects, should they appear twice in the final result or just once?

Comment: I think this should really be 2 separate queries...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT TOP 10 A.*, 0 AS Ordinal
      FROM A
      ORDER BY [Price]) AS A1

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT TOP 3 A.*, 1 AS Ordinal
      FROM A
      ORDER BY [Name]) AS A2

ORDER BY Ordinal
```

From [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx):

> In a query that uses UNION, EXCEPT, or INTERSECT operators, ORDER BY
>   is allowed only at the end of the statement. This restriction applies
>   only to when you specify UNION, EXCEPT and INTERSECT in a top-level
>   query **and not in a subquery**.

**Edited**: to force the order you need to apply an `ORDER BY` to the outer query. I've added a constant value column to both queries.

Comment: I'm under the impression that the OP would want them ordered in the final result (the 10 price followed by the 3 name) and I don't think this can 100% guarantee that result

Comment: There is *no* guarantee on the order in which results are returned by a `UNION ALL` (nor `UNION`) unless *it* has an `ORDER BY` clause applied.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Does that mean that it's not guaranteed that both queries are appended?

Comment: No, it means that it *could* return the 1st row from the first query, then the 1st and 2nd rows from the second query, then the 2nd, 3rd and 4th rows from the first query, 3rd row from second query, and then the remaining rows from the first query. And, in fact, it's not even guaranteed to return them in the sort orders of the subqueries - it could, for whatever reason, choose to reorder the results. If you don't have an `ORDER BY` on the outer query, you can assume *nothing* about the final results

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Would it help to add a foo column which we can order by? For example a constant numerical value in the first query and a higher in the second query. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have been trying this in SQL Server 2017 and @Damien_The_Unbeliever seems to be correct, it only respects the outer most `ORDER BY` regardless of my inner `ORDER BY` statements with even the simplest sample data (10 rows, 3 columns).  Anyone have any thoughts on this?  Perhaps it worked in 2012, but doesn't appear to work anymore:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4fe69c/1

Comment: @akousmata - it's **never** been guaranteed to work. `ORDER BY` within subqueries, etc, is *solely there to help define other parts of the language* like `TOP`. That's why you're prevented from using it alone. It's never been *meant* to work but people continue to peddle myths about stable ordering without using the one tool you're meant to use - `ORDER BY` on the outermost query.

Answer (score 4):

This is a real hacky way to do this. You probably want these as separate queries in reality, but this should give you the result you want...

```
select *
from (
  select top 10 *, 1 as 'ord', price as 'ordprice' from A
  union 
  select top 3 *, 2 as 'ord', 0 as 'ordprice' from A
) a
order by ord, ordprice, name
```

Answer (score 2):

UNION doesn't like ORDER by clauses in the UNIONed expressions.
Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT TOP 10 * FROM A ORDER BY Price) SetA
UNION
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT TOP 3 * FROM a ORDER BY name) Setb
[ORDER BY something]
```

This spoofs the UNION operator into ignoring the ORDER BYs, which still operate correctly on the TOP operator.
You can apply a final ORDER BY to order the UNIONed set, if you like.

[No longer applies exactly to your question now that it's edited!]

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 10 *,0 as RS from A
union
select top 3 *,1 as RS from A 
order by
    RS,
    CASE WHEN RS=0 THEN price END, --Don't affect RS 1
    name
```

Answer (score -2):

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 0 AS Employee_ID, 'No Employees' as Employee_FullName , 'id1' Orderkey
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT Employee_ID, Employee_FullName, 'id2' Orderkey
        FROM  tblEmployee
        ORDER BY Orderkey, Employee_FullName"

ds = dbconn.SelectQuery(cmd)

ds.Tables(0).Columns.Remove(ds.Tables(0).Columns("Orderkey"))

Comment: Welcom to SO. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)