# Using ORDER BY with UNION: NULL issue

Tags: sql

I got correct numbers for everything but when I tried to use `ORDER BY` clause, it works but Average GPA row goes top of the datas. It should be at the end.

I tried `ISNULL`, `GROUPING` but both of them did not work.

```
SELECT se.sectionid AS sectionid, st.lname AS last_name, st.fname AS first_name, g.letter AS letter, FORMAT(AVG(gs.point),2) AS gpa 
FROM student as st, section as se, grade as g, grade_scale as gs 
WHERE st.studentid = g.studentid AND se.sectionid = g.sectionid AND g.letter = gs.letter AND se.sectionid = 35
GROUP BY sectionid, last_name, first_name, letter
UNION
SELECT 'Average GPA','', '','', FORMAT(AVG(gs.point),2) AS gpa 
FROM student as st, section as se, grade as g, grade_scale as gs 
WHERE st.studentid = g.studentid AND se.sectionid = g.sectionid AND g.letter = gs.letter AND se.sectionid = 35
ORDER BY last_name, first_name;
```

The Average GPA row should be at the bottom and anything that I searched on Google does not work. This table should be sorted by last_name and first_name.

Thank you!

Comment: You tagged the question with PHP and HTML, yet the code is neither. Did you make a mistake? It is in your best interest to use correct tags.

Comment: `ISNULL()` is specific to MSSQL (aka SQL-Server)

Comment: @Dharman ah, my mistake. I think I was thinking of `IFNULL()` which is MySQL specific

Comment: Howdy.  Try this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454815/using-different-order-by-with-union

Comment: @BattlFrog This might be a good link, but OP should first clarify which DB they are using.

Comment: Thank you! I solved it. This is my time using stackoverflow so I missed a lot of things. Sorry for that!