# SQL Query for sorting in particular order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have this data:

| parent_id | comment_id | comment_level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | 0xB2 | 1 |
| NULL | 0xB6 | 1 |
| NULL | 0xBA | 1 |
| NULL | 0xBE | 1 |
| NULL | 0xC110 | 1 |
| NULL | 0xC130 | 1 |
| 123 | 0xC13580 | 2 |
| 456 | 0xC135AC | 3 |
| 123 | 0xC13680 | 2 |

I want the result in such a way that rows where comment_level=1 should be in descending order by comment_id and other rows(i.e. where comment_level!=1) should be in ascending order by comment_id but the order of comment level greater than 1 should be inserted according to to order of comment level 1 (what I mean is that rows with comment_level=1 should remain in descending order and then rows with comment_level!=1 should be inserted in increasing order but it should be inserted following rows where comment_id is less than it)

Result should look like this

```
NULL    0xC130     1
123     0xC13580   2
456     0xC135AC   3
123     0xC13680   2
NULL    0xC110     1
NULL    0xBE       1
NULL    0xBA       1
NULL    0xB6       1
NULL    0xB2       1
```

Note the bold rows in above sort by comment_id in ascending order, but they come after their "main" row (with comment_level =  1), where these main rows sort DESC by comment_id.

I tried creating 2 tables for different comment level and used sorting for union but it didn't work out because 2 different order by doesn't work maybe I tried from this [Using different order by with union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454815/using-different-order-by-with-union) but it gave me an error and after all even if this worked it still might not have given me the whole answer.

Comment: I really don't follow what you are trying to say in the first sentence. I suggest breaking it down more.

Comment: Yes, I know it doesn't look good. Can you see the output I'm expecting?

Comment: I've updated the question please have a look at it

Comment: You need to use spaces on this site for the table formatting. The tabs will render inconsistently depending on what device and browser users have.

Comment: Thanks I didn't knew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're going for, and a `UNION` will not be able to do it.

To accomplish this, each row needs to match with a specific "parent" row that does have `1` for the `comment_level`. If the `comment_level` is already `1`, the row is its own parent. Then we can sort first by the `comment_id` from that parent record DESC, and then sort ascending by the local `comment_id` within the a given group of matching parent records.

You'll need something like this:

```
SELECT t0.*
FROM [MyTable] t0
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 comment_id 
    FROM [MyTable] t1 
    WHERE t1.comment_level = 1 AND t1.comment_id <= t0.comment_id 
    ORDER BY t1.comment_id DESC
) parents
ORDER BY parents.comment_id DESC, 
    case when t0.comment_level = 1 then 0 else 1 end, 
    t0.comment_id
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/qZBb3YjO

There's probably also a solution using a windowing function that will be more efficient.

---

And here it is:

```
SELECT parent_id, comment_id, comment_level 
FROM (
    SELECT t0.*, t1.comment_id as t1_comment_id
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t0.comment_id ORDER BY t1.comment_id desc) rn 
    FROM [MyTable] t0
    LEFT JOIN [MyTable] t1 ON t1.comment_level = 1 and t1.comment_id <= t0.comment_id
) d
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY t1_comment_id DESC,
  case when comment_level = 1 then 0 else 1 end,
  comment_id
```

See it here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/me1vGNdM

Comment: Yes exactly I want to do that and using this it is giving partially correct all comment_level >1 are ascending order but not below their parent.

Comment: @AditMehta Putting them below their parent is what the `case` expression in the `order by` clause is for. Maybe adjust that to get this working.

Comment: Otherwise, if you can add a few more rows to the sample data and results to show where it's going wrong, that would help, because the fiddle provides the exact same output as was expected in the question.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this and possibly the only one is create two separate queries and `union` them together. Something like:

```sql
(select * from table where comment_level = 1 order by comment_id desc)
union
(select * from table where not comment_level = 1 order by comment_id asc)
```

Comment: I have already tried this I can't use 2 order by in one union

Comment: try it including  parentheces

Answer (score 0):

Those varbinary values aren't arbitrary, they're hierarchyid values. And just a guess, they're probably typed that way in the schema (it's too much to be a coincidence). We can use this fact to do what we're looking to do.

```sql
with d_raw as (
    select * from (values
        (NULL, 0xC130  , 1),
        (123 , 0xC13580, 2),
        (456 , 0xC135AC, 3),
        (123 , 0xC13680, 2),
        (NULL, 0xC110  , 1),
        (NULL, 0xBE    , 1),
        (NULL, 0xBA    , 1),
        (NULL, 0xB6    , 1),
        (NULL, 0xB2    , 1)
    ) as x(parent_id, comment_id, comment_level)
),
d as (
    select parent_id, comment_id = cast(comment_id as hierarchyid), comment_level
    from d_raw
)
select *,
    comment_id.ToString(), 
    comment_id.GetAncestor(comment_id.GetLevel() - 1).ToString()
from d
order by comment_id.GetAncestor(comment_id.GetLevel() - 1) desc, 
    comment_id
```

Note - the CTEs that I'm using are just to get the data into the right format and the last SELECT adds additional columns just to show what's going on; you can omit them from your query without consequence. I think the only interesting part of this solution is using `comment_id.GetAncestor(comment_id.GetLevel() - 1)` to get the root-level node.